# save datetime in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have table in mysql database which have field with datatype is datetime.

I want to save the datetime in this minute, for this I use  " Now() ", but it does not work,

It just save 000000000000 in databaes.

Comment: Can you please provide the code?

Comment: Please take the time to use correct spelling and grammar if you want people to help you.  Then, post your code snippet of SQL or PHP.

Comment: And accept your answer if you wish that we will help you!

Comment: Table structure can also help

Answer (score 12):

If you use **php**, the correct format is:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

UPDATE:
Minutes are expressed as `i` not `m`

Comment: I always use this too... nice to see that other people use this way too.

Answer (score 4):

If you've got a timestamp in PHP check out FROM_UNIXTIME() 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

```
$tstamp = time();

$query = "INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME($tstamp))";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT ... (Now(), ...)
```

without additional quotes around the function Now()

Answer (score 1):

I would use function `time()` too, then it's easy to output different kind of timestamps with `date()`.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (".time().");";
```

Answer (score 0):

`date("g")` this will return 12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros. For more options see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

**An example of a PHP script which sets a date in MySQL manually,**

```
<?php
$query_date = "INSERT INTO tablename (col_name, col_date) VALUES ('DATE: Manual Date', '2008-7-04')”;
mysql_query($query_date) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

**An example of a PHP script which sets a date in MySQL Automatic,**

```
<?php
$query_date = "INSERT INTO tablename (col_name, col_date) VALUE ('DATE: Auto CURDATE()',  CURDATE() )”;
mysql_query($query_date) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: set the 'type' of column named 'date_time' as 'DATETIME' and run the following query:

INSERT INTO my_table (`date_time`) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)